# Dirac differential operator and anti-commutation relations

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I was studying Dirac's equation and my book says the following. Let $D = i \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$, where $\partial_{0} = \partial/\partial t$ and $\partial_{\mu} = \partial / \partial x_{\mu}$ if $\mu = 1,2,3$. Here, $\gamma^{\mu}$ are coefficients to be determined. Then:
$$D^{2} = \frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}$$
But why is that? I thought this would be (I'm expliciting the summations so I don't get lost):
$$D = i\sum_{\mu=0}^{4}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} \Rightarrow D^{2} = -\sum_{\mu,\nu=0}^{4}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}$$

Why is that wrong?

Comment: Either way, as far as I understand the operator $D^{2}$ comes up when we want to show that the (free) Dirac Field like every other vector or scalar field, satisfies the Klein-Gordon Equation. Therefore, a sign here and there really shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing, if we want to get that answer, we need $(-i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu)(i\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu)$ since $\gamma^\mu$ are not Hermitian, we can't  use  $D^2=D^\dagger D$.

if we use $D^2=DD$, we will get an extra minus sign.

Any way, I think the idea is show that Dirac equation implies K-G equation.

$D^2=D D=-\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu=-\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu\partial_\nu\partial_\mu=-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$

$2D^2=-(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu)\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=-\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$

$D^2=-\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$

Comment: Why $D^2=D^{\dagger}D$ and no $D^2=DD$?, o what is $DD$?

Comment: $\gamma$ matrices are not Hermitian!!

Comment: It is confusing indeed! I got the same answer myself, but it shouldn't be with the minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=\partial_\nu\partial_\mu$, $[\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu]\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=0$, so $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=\tfrac12\{\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu\}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but at that time the book does not specify what the $\gamma^{\mu}$ are (as I mentioned, these are to be defined) so how can I conclude that $[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]=0$?

Comment: @MathMath **I don't.** I use the fact that contracting an antisymmetric quantity with a symmetric one gives $0$.